# Yeoman Angular app, grunt watch .less files

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs, yeoman

I playing around with Yeoman, grunt, bower, bootstrap and the yo Angular app. Im trying to make grunt watch .less files but Im having some trouble.
I have of course done installed the grunt-contrib-less module with

```
npm install grunt-contrib-less --save-dev
```

and made it save to my package.json.

I have been able to make this work in other projects with the code:

```
  module.exports = function(grunt){
        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg:grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            less:{
                development:{
                        options: {
                            paths: ['bower_components/bootstrap/less', 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css'],
                                   yuicompress: true
                        },
                    files:{
                        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' : 'bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less',
                    }
                }
            },
            // running 'grunt watch' will watch for changes
            watch: {
                files: ['bower_components/bootstrap/less/*.less', 'bower_components/bootstrap/less/*.less'],
                       tasks: ['less']
            }
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.registerTask('default',['less']);
    };
```

and:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
      grunt.initConfig({
          less: {
              development: {
                  options: {
                      paths: ["bower_components/bootstrap/less"],
                      yuicompress: true
                  },
                  files: {
                      "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css": "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
                  }
              }
          },
          watch: {
              files: "bower_components/bootstrap/less/*",
              tasks: ["less"]
          }
      });
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

but I have not tried whit an Angular app before. It may also be something as simple as I have done the routing wrong, but I have tried so many times now Im not sure if its that.
The full thing is also on github https://github.com/Lumberfella/angularApp.git

I already have some watch code in the Gruntfile.js

```
watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['bowerInstall']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },
```

and would like something like (not real functioning code I think)

```
less: {
  files: [
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/something.something}*.less'
  ]
  tasks: ['less:developer']
},
```

to watch the .less files and make it into a css file if possible.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is quite simple, because I had the solution code in the question. The only difficult thing for me was where and how to put it.

First I installed the grunt-contrib-less module and made another bootstrap less folder in my styles folder instead of in bower_components (thank you Mingos !).
Then I my updatet Gruntfile and this is what it looks like now:

```
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                compress: true,
                yuicompress: true,
                optimization: 2
            },
            files: {
                // target.css file: source.less file
                "app/styles/bootstrap.css": "app/styles/less/bootstrap.less"
            }
        }
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['bowerInstall']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css', '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/less/{,*/}*.less'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer', 'less']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    bowerInstall: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bowerInstall',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'bowerInstall',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

As you can see this made a new bootstrap.css in my styles folder which I then linked from my index.html :)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with the newest version of yeoman. Very helpful for a newbie like myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the files to watch in a subtask:

```
watch: {
    less: {
        files: "bower_components/bootstrap/less/*",
        tasks: ["less"]
    }
}
```

Also, a remark: are you sure you want to watch for changes in files sucked in via Bower? Wouldn't it make more sense to watch a directory where you edit your own code instead of the component?

Comment: Im not sure. would that mean that I would have to move files manually? 
I also see no problem in watching it from the bower_component directory. I can see from the code above it only watches the changes done to the less code but it doesn't update the bootstrap.css (does it) which Im linkin to from my index.html

Comment: What I mean is that editing the files contained in Bower's components dir is a bad idea because after you run `bower update`, your changes might well get overwritten by a newer version of the component. If you want to use Bootstrap's files in your custom stylesheet, `@import` them instead.

Comment: But what if I want to edit the bootstraps less files and still @import them from the bower components to a custom stylesheet. Wouldn't what I edited in the bootstraps less files get overwritten anyways if I updated? Im just looking for the simplest way to do this where everything is automagic. :)

Comment: That's what I just wrote: your changes may be overwritten after a `bower update`. As a general rule: never modify anything inside your `bower_components` dir. Make a copy and edit that, but don't touch the original files. The whole idea behind Bower is that whenever a new version comes out or perhaps whenever some package requires a given version of a library as a dependency, Bower can be used to replace the outdated code.

Comment: ahh.. ok. Took me a while to get it. Thank you! Now back to the first question. How can I make it so the code above make the less files update the bootstrap.css which Im linking to from my index.html?

Comment: I have already answered that. Write the correct task config in your `Gruntfile.js` and then run `grunt watch` to start watching, there's nothing more to it.

Comment: what I meant was, how can I make it so bower watches the less files and updates the css?
tried (with the code you answered with) to add inn:    `["bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css":"bower_components/bootstrap/less/*"]` after in files:

Comment: The code you mention in the comment in invalid JavaScript (object notation in an array).
The code I posted should work fine. Either your `less` task is faulty (check by running it directly) or the watched files did not change. Or the watch task isn't running.